# apex rest method accepting an object

Tags: apex, json

Im trying to create an endpoint to allow a third party hit a url rest endpoint with a webhook request when some processing has been done on there side.
I am accepting data back from a webhook and I need my method to be able to accept an object.

Through workbench I am able to hit this endpoint and print some lines to the logs. I can even send simple data objects(Not nested objects). With the data being nested, thats where I'm getting confused.

I have been following this trailhead to get an idea about creating a REST resource: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices?trail_id=force_com_dev_intermediate

here is the json that I will receive.

```
{
  "data": {
    "customerId": 1191857,
    "leadNumber": "this is a lead number",
    "generatedDate": "2021-09-03T19:51:56.896Z",
    "proposalRequest": null,
    "cadDesignComplete": {
      "designLink":
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/phoenix-cloud-storage/local/customer_file/asdf.zip"
    }
  },
  "event": "cadDesignComplete"
}
```

Here is the code I've written so far. not much but maybe a start

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CadDesignUrl/*')
global with sharing class CadDesignUrlWebHook {
  @HttpPut
  global static String updateCadWithCadDesignUrl(/*do I accept data in params?*/) {
    // will it have something to do with this below?
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

    /* TODO: -
     rest of function will make an update with data.
    */
        
  }
}
```

The next step is going to be adding authentication to this endpoint, If anyone can lead me to the right place that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the authentication bit, all requests to Salesforce endpoints require authentication by default. Salesforce "public sites" are the only exception to that which I know. Salesforce uses OAuth 2.0 ([general help page for OAuth flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm)) as the main authentication mechanism, and offers a collection of different "flows" that you can use. For server-to-server communication (i.e. if this third party system can't present users with a popup to have them log into your Salesforce org), you'd be looking at the JWT Bearer flow.

As for getting the data from the request itself, the trailhead module you linked does go into some detail about that.

You *can* specify parameters in the signature of your `@HttpPut` annotated method like so

```
@HttpPut
  global static String updateCadWithCadDesignUrl(Map<String, Object> data, String event) {
```

and Salesforce will attempt to deserialize the data included in the request body and put it into those parameters.

Generally though, I prefer the flexibility of doing the deserialization myself. If your `@HttpPut` method takes no parameters, then Salesforce will copy the body of the request into `RestRequest.Request.requestBody` (getting access to the `RestRequest` instance is something that Salesforce takes care of automatically when you use one of the `@HttpX` annotations).

The request body is given to us as a Blob, and needs to be converted to a string to be of much use. After that, you're free to deserialize it. For JSON, common practice is to define a class (or several classes, which could be an *inner class* of your `CadDesignUrlWebHook`) that mimics the structure of the JSON data.

Given your example so far, getting the data from the request body would look something like this

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/some/path')
global class CadDesignUrlWebHook {
    public class RequestData {
        public Data data;
        public String event;
    }

    public class Data {
        public Integer customerId;
        public String leadNumber;
        public DateTime generatedDate;
        public String proposalRequest;
        public CadDesign cadDesignComplete;
    }

    public class CadDesign {
        public String designLink;
    }

    @HttpPut
    global static void handlePUT(){
        RequestData reqData = (RequestData)JSON.deserialize(RestContext.Request.requestBody.toString(), RequestData.class);

        // By spending a little effort to make deserialization classes, accessing the
        //   data becomes a simple affair
        system.debug(reqData.data.cadDesignComplete.designLink);

        // If you choose to deserializeUntyped instead, you'll need to do type-casting
        //   at every level of data that you want to access.
        // I prefer typed deserialization to untyped deserialization, but both have
        //   their place.
        // This is also what you'd end up doing if you let Salesforce deserialize
        //   multi-level request bodies (and don't have deserialization classes)
        Map<String, Object> untypedData = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(RestContext.Request.requestBody.toString());
        Map<String, Object> untypedInnerData = (Map<String, Object>)untypedData.get('data');
        Map<String, Object> untypedCadData = (Map<String, Object>)untypedInnerData.get('cadDesignComplete');
        system.debug((String)untypedCadData.get('designLink'));

        // Other logic to follow, outside of the scope of this question
    }
}
```

One last note. If you find yourself wanting/needing more details about something than a trailhead module provides, the next logical step is to consult Salesforce's developer documentation. Salesforce's own documentation search can be pretty hit or miss these days, but searching for `<some class> class apex` in your search engine of choice usually does pretty good.

You'll probably want to read through the [RestRequest class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_System_RestRequest_requestBody) (I've included an anchor to the `requestBody` property).

Salesforce documentation is usually pretty good about linking to other, useful, related documentation pages, and the RestRequest documentation is where I confirmed my statement about how `requestBody` behaves.

Comment: Best answer I could have received. Thank you.
The second way and deserializing it yourself would be considered DTO(Data Transfer Objects) correct?

Comment: Also one more question, I don't have best code practices in SF as I am just helping out a bit. I have another end point I need to write that called '/EngineeringUrl/' do I need to create another class that has the @RestResource(urlMapping=''EngineeringUrl) at the top of the class? or is there another way to have them both in the same class?

Comment: @Trey I suppose it could be a DTO, though I'm not entirely sure (nor am I too concerned about it). You could use a wildcard in the urlMapping, but changing your annotation to be `@RestResource(urlMapping='/*')` isn't something I'd recommend at all. That would end up meaning your one class has to dispatch to every other rest resource you would create in the future (and Salesforce already handles dispatching for us). Using the wildcard when it's deeper in the URI (e.g. `@RestResource(urlMapping='/baseUrl/specific/*)` ) may have some uses, but in general you should just create another class.